# Prove that (a+bc) + (a'(b'+c')) = 1

Tags: boolean-algebra

Im trying to prove the boolean expression `(a+bc)` is the complement of `(a'(b'+c'))`. To do that I need to prove that `(a+bc) + (a'(b'+c')) = 1`, however I only get as far as:

```
(a + bc + a')(a + bc + b' + c')
(a + a' + bc)(a + bc + b' + c')
(1 + bc)(a + bc + b' + c')
1(a + bc + b' + c')
```

What property can I use to reduce the RHS?

Comment: Use that $b'+c'=(bc)'$ for example.

Comment: Alternatively: $\overline{\bar{a}(\bar{b}+\bar{c})}= \overline{\bar{a}}+\overline{\bar{b}+\bar{c}}=a+bc$

Answer (score 0):

You're doing very well! Now, recall that $$b'+c'=(bc)',$$ so that we get $$a+bc+(bc)'.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: `a + bc + (bc)' = a + 1 = 1`; thus `(1)(1) = 1` proving the complement?

Comment: Well, not quite. You've done half of the job. You also need to show that $$(a+bc)\bigl(a'(b'+c')\bigr)=0.$$

Comment: Yea working on that part now, perhaps I meant proving the first part?!

Answer (score 0):

$$a \lor bc \lor \overline a(\overline b \lor \overline c)=1$$
I use this rule: $a=a \lor a \overline b=a \lor a \overline c$.
$$[a \lor bc \lor \overline a \overline b \lor \overline a \cdot \overline c] \lor a \overline b \lor a \overline c =1 $$
You should remember that $ x \lor \overline x = 1$.
$$ a \lor \overline b \lor \overline c \lor bc =1$$
$$ a \lor \overline b \lor \overline c \lor bc \lor \overline b c =1$$
$$ a \lor \overline b \lor \overline c \lor c =1$$
$$ a \lor \overline b \lor 1 =1$$
So, this function is always true.